# Cannot change Windows Service properties: Error 87: The parameter is incorrect

Tags: windows, service

I'm trying to disable a service in Windows 10 from the Control Panel > Administrative Tools > Services snap in.

- Service Name: **OneSyncSvc_1e21e**
- Display Name: **Sync Host_1e21e**
- Description: This service synchronizes mail, contacts, calendar and various other user data.  Mail and other applications dependent on this functionality will not work properly when this service is not running.
- Path to executable: C:\WINDOWS\system32\svchost.exe -k UnistackSvcGroup
- Startup type: **Automatic (Delayed Start)**

When I try to change the Startup type to **Manual** or **Disabled** and press OK, I get this message:

> The parameter is incorrect.

When I try to change the Startup type to **Automatic** and press OK, I get this message:

> The delayed auto-start flag could not be reset.
>
> Error 87: The parameter is incorrect.

When I try to change the 'Log on as' user to a user without any privileges, I get this message:

> The parameter is incorrect.

I've done some searches online and within the stack exchange network, but the error message is a pretty common one and the articles I've found seem to apply to trying to install services and/or dependencies through code.  I'm just using the basic windows GUI.

Is there any way I can correct this error, disable this service, or delete it entirely?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I stumbled upon the same issue when trying to disable MessagingService_48ab2.

The solution for it was to look for the service in the registry.

Press start button on your keyboard, type regedit, right-click it and open as administrator.

Then navigate to:
**Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\OneSyncSvc_48ab2**

Double-click the "**Start**" 32-bit DWORD and change it's value to **4** (disabled).

Comment: 5 Years later and this answer just saved my bacon.  In my case, it wasn't the inability to change the `Startup Type`, it was the inability to start the service entirely.  For my case, I found the Path for the Service was listed as `""C:\PathToService\Service.exe""` instead of `"C:\PathToService\Service.exe"` - For some reason the installer added 2 double quotes making a nice fubar.

Answer (score 4):

Answer by askepott is the only right one.

The other answers don't take into account the crucial "The parameter is incorrect" part of the original question: PowerShell is just a dumb shell that relays the command to the same service component that fails the OP in the first place:

```
> Get-Service -Name "ServiceName"" | Set-Service -StartupType Disabled -Confirm:$false
Set-Service : Service 'ServiceName (ServiceName)' cannot be configured due to the following error: The parameter
is incorrect
At line:1 char:35
+ ... ame ServiceName | Set-Service -StartupType Disabled -Confirm:$false
+                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController:ServiceController) [Set-Servi
   ce], ServiceCommandException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CouldNotSetService,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetServiceCommand
```

Editing the registry seems to be the only solution for botched services like this. I don't know the cause of this issue, but in my case the service seemed to be configured to run with 'Log on as', with the user password provided but an empty username. Changing it to Local System wouldn't work either due to the "The parameter is incorrect" persisting with any modification.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use powershell to disable the service (or any other PITA service)

Start powershell as Administration (Run as Administration)
and then

```
Get-Service -Name OneSyncSvc | Set-Service -StartupType Disabled -Confirm:$false
```

Comment: This is much easier (and safer) than running regedit.

Comment: Does not work, the script executed w/o errors, but the Service Manager still shows `Automatic (Delayed startup)`.

Comment: @Andry OneSyncSvc is a "per-user service" based on a "template" service per https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/application-management/per-user-services-in-windows. The shown command *does* work to change the template service, though this presumably means that it won't take effect until the user's next login. A downside of using this method is that it requires PowerShell 7+ to undo it since the default value is `AutomaticDelayedStart`, which isn't supported in PowerShell 5.1 (currently preinstalled with Windows 10).

Answer (score 2):

This type of service is apparently what's called a "per-user service", which is generated from a "template" service visible in this registry under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services per https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/application-management/per-user-services-in-windows.

To change both the per-user and template services simultaneously, the easiest method appears to be the PowerShell command `Set-ItemProperty -Path "Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\OneSyncSvc*" -Name "Start" -Value 4` (tested in PowerShell 5.1/7.1) where `4` corresponds to the "Disabled" value in the Services app (services.msc). (`2` corresponds to the "Automatic (Delayed Start)" value.)

The template service can also be changed with the PowerShell command `Get-Service -Name OneSyncSvc | Set-Service -StartupType "Disabled"` and undone in PowerShell 7+ with the command `Get-Service -Name OneSyncSvc | Set-Service -StartupType "AutomaticDelayedStart"`.

You may want to take note of the default values first so that any changes made can be undone afterward by using a command like `Get-ItemProperty -Path "Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\OneSyncSvc*" | Select-Object "Start"`.

This can also be done with the PowerShell commands `Get-Service -Name OneSyncSvc | Select-Object "Name", "StartupType"; Get-Service -Name OneSyncSvc* | Select-Object "Name", "StartupType"`.

Answer (score 0):

These are per user services and are created when a user logs on and deleted when a user logs off. keeps things separated for security reasons. if you disable the template service then the per user service will be created in the same state. if i understand this correctly. taken from this site. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/application-management/per-user-services-in-windows

Comment: mostly with more sub information it could get a great idea and answer

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).